# Have two HTML form icons in one line without moving content

Tags: html, css

Current output:

[image]

Expected Output:

[image]

Which is achieved when I do not use forms, here is the current code:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.0/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-xh6O/CkQoPOWDdYTDqeRdPCVd1SpvCA9XXcUnZS2FmJNp1coAFzvtCN9BmamE+4aHK8yyUHUSCcJHgXloTyT2A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <form>
        <button type="submit">
                <i class="fa-solid fa-minus"></i>
            </button>
      </form>
      &nbsp; {{row.2}} &nbsp;
      <form>
        <button type="submit">
                <i class="fa-solid fa-plus"></i>
            </button>
      </form>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turning your `td` into a flex container should do the trick. In my example I changed the `td` to a `div` and gave it the class `contain` because the `td` was dissapearing in the output without the rest of the table.

If you can edit the html, adding a class to that td and using that to target in your css is the best option, if you target the `td` on its own you will probably affect some other areas of your form that you didn't intend to

Also, is there a reason you're using `form` tags instead of just `div` to wrap the icon buttons?

```css
.contain {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.0/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-xh6O/CkQoPOWDdYTDqeRdPCVd1SpvCA9XXcUnZS2FmJNp1coAFzvtCN9BmamE+4aHK8yyUHUSCcJHgXloTyT2A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>

<div class="contain">
  <form>
    <button type="submit">
            <i class="fa-solid fa-minus"></i>
        </button>
  </form>
  &nbsp; {{row.2}} &nbsp;
  <form>
    <button type="submit">
            <i class="fa-solid fa-plus"></i>
        </button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the `form` elements inline elements with `display: inline;`

```css
form {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.0/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-xh6O/CkQoPOWDdYTDqeRdPCVd1SpvCA9XXcUnZS2FmJNp1coAFzvtCN9BmamE+4aHK8yyUHUSCcJHgXloTyT2A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>


<td>
  <form>
    <button type="submit">
      <i class="fa-solid fa-minus"></i>
    </button>
  </form>
  &nbsp; {{row.2}} &nbsp;
  <form>
    <button type="submit">
      <i class="fa-solid fa-plus"></i>
    </button>
  </form>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can split your td cell in three subcell by adding tr > td * 3:

```
<td>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <form>
                <button type="submit">
                    <i class="fa-solid fa-minus"></i>
                </button>
            </form>
        </td>
        <td>
            &nbsp; {{row.2}} &nbsp;
        </td>
        <td>
            <form>
                <button type="submit">
                    <i class="fa-solid fa-plus"></i>
                </button>
            </form>
        </td>
    </tr>
</td>
```